# Magento 2 not sending any emails

Tags: magento2, error, email, magento2.2.6, smtp

I'm having an issue with magento **not sending any emails**. I've already tested some solutions and it's not worked.

I'm using a **SMTP extension** and **Magento 2.2.6**: https://github.com/mageplaza/magento-2-smtp
And always **getting an error** when testing the extensions configs:
[image]

I also checked var/log and no errors were found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found a solution. My host provider (Digital Ocean) was blocking outgoing mails. I conctacted them and I was able to test successfully and send emails.

Answer (score 1):

As there is no error in the logs, it seems that `Disable Email Communications` option in **Mail Sending Settings** is set to `Yes`, . Please, follow these steps:

1. Head to **Stores > Configuration > Advanced > System**.
2. `Find Disable Email Communications` option under **Mail Sending
   Settings**. Set it to `No`.

It should fix your issue.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your reply but It's not the case. **Mail Sending Settings** is already marked as 'No'

Answer (score 0):

1. Hosting Provider Block Sending ports
   Your hosting/server may block 25, 465, or 587 port.
2. Firewall
   Your server firewall may block the SMTP host or ports, try to check these things.

Comment: 1. I already contacted my host provider to check if there is anything blocking outgoing mail, I'm just waiting for an answer... 2. Is there a way so I can check this through SSH?